# Error when getting values from the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I coded for getting values from the JTable and get that value for do calculations.

```
//getting user input for selling qty 
        String Qty=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Selling Quantity :");
        double sellingqty=Double.parseDouble(Qty);

      //getting user input for specific item discount
        String discount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert Item Discount");
        double idiscount=Double.parseDouble(discount);

for(j=0;j<100;j++){
           double icost =(double) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(j,2); 
        System.out.print(icost);

      //calculating Gross Total  
        double grosstotal = (sellingqty*icost)-idiscount;

        System.out.println(grosstotal);

        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
         //setting qty input value to table sale  
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(sellingqty,i, 3);
        //setting input value to table sale  
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(idiscount,i, 4); 
        //setting grosstotal value to table sale
        tableSale.getModel().setValueAt(grosstotal,i, 5); 
        }

       }
```

When I execute the code shows a null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.bit.project.Newsale.add_btnActionPerformed(Newsale.java: 710) at 
com.bit.project.Newsale.access$800(Newsale.java: 37) at 
com.bit.project.Newsale$12.actionPerformed(Newsale.java: 469) at 
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java: 2022) at 
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java: 2022) at 
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java: 2346)
```

This line shows the Null Pointer Exception

```
 double icost =(double) tableSale.getModel().getValueAt(j,3);
```

What is the error here?

Comment: where does it show NPE? can you also post the stacktrace?

Comment: @karthik sorry :( I added the 710 line in the question..

Comment: @tenten how much rows are there in your table?

Comment: So either tableSale is null, of the value returned by tableSale.getModel() is null. Use your debugger to find out, or just add traces in the code.

Comment: @tenten are you sure that `tableSale.getModel()` is not null?

Comment: @FastSnail currently no rows.. I coded to add specific row, when click of a button. above code executes after adding the row.

Comment: @tenten as JB Nizet said, you should put a debug point at line 710, and check what is null in that line.